# Entity Framework, Only selecting newest reference entry of table

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework

It's hard to explain, but currently I have a SQL database with a table called
**Stocks**. There are some tables which have a reference to the Stock table, like **Rating** where there can be multiple results for the same stock.

Now when I query a specific stock from my database with EF, I receive my main object but also a list of **Ratings** with it.

My Stock-Table:

- Id
- Name

My Stock-Rating-Table:

- Id
- StockId
- Result
- Timestamp

How is it possible to select only the newest entry of the Rating-table, so I have a single object and not the whole list of entries attached to my Stock object?

Comment: Combination of `FirstOrDefault` and `OrderBy` a date column? Without providing your entities and tables it's hard to provide you an exact answer.

Comment: The "StockRating" table has a timestamp for each record. But I'm not used to the syntax of entity framework at all.

It must be something like:
(From s In db.Stocks Select s, x.StockRating.OrderByDescending(Function(t) t.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault).ToList

But that makes the outcoming list a list of anonymous objects :/

Comment: Well it's not specifically EF just Linq. Not sure about having a single entity returned from a one-to-many relationship. Could put a `NotMapped` property though which which gets the latest entry from the collection of Ratings on the Stock entity. Main problem is if you have lots of ratings which you wouldn't really want to load.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `StockId` then you query the `StockRating` table.

```
Dim query = model.StockRating.Where(Function(sr) sr.StockId = _stockId)
                 .OrderByDescending(Function(o) o.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault
```